Не работает Python файл после конвертации в EXE
Конвертировал с помощью pyinstaller своё приложение, но после процедуры, при запуске .exe файла, выходит ошибка:
  File "godmode.py", line 171, in <module>
  File "godmode.py", line 16, in __init__
  File "godmode.py", line 24, in initUI
  IndexError: list index out of range 

Вот сам код:
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout,
    QLabel, QFrame, QSpacerItem)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFontDatabase, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Быстрый доступ'
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon.png"))

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setFixedSize(550, 350)

        # ----------- Проблема тут ------------
        QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("nunito.ttf")
        font_family = QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies(0)[0]

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()

        vbox_left = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox_right = QVBoxLayout()

        label_left = QLabel("Системные")
        label_left.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        label_right = QLabel("Сторонние")
        label_right.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)

        left_column = QFrame()
        left_column.setLayout(vbox_left)

        right_column = QFrame()
        right_column.setLayout(vbox_right)

        vbox_left.addWidget(label_left)
        vbox_right.addWidget(label_right)

        buttons_left = [
            ('Диспетчер задач', self.on_task_manager_click),
            ('Панель управления', self.on_control_panel_click),
            ('Автозагрузка', self.on_open_autostart_folder_click),
            ('Командная строка', self.on_open_cmd_click),
            ('Редактор реестра', self.on_open_registry_editor_click),
            ('Конфигуратор системы', self.on_open_msconfig_click),
            ('Свойства системы', self.on_open_sysprop_click)
        ]

        buttons_right = [
            ('Process Hacker', self.on_open_process_hacker_click),
            ('AIDA64', self.on_open_aida64_click),
            ('Total Uninstall', self.on_open_total_uninstall_click),
            ('Hard Disk Sentinel', self.on_open_hard_disk_sentinel_click)
        ]

        for text, action in buttons_left:
            button = QPushButton(text)
            button.setFixedHeight(30)
            vbox_left.addSpacerItem(QSpacerItem(0, 3))
            button.clicked.connect(action)
            vbox_left.addWidget(button)
        for text, action in buttons_right:
            button = QPushButton(text)
            button.setFixedHeight(30)
            vbox_right.addSpacerItem(QSpacerItem(0, 3))
            button.clicked.connect(action)
            vbox_right.addWidget(button)

        hbox.addWidget(left_column)
        hbox.addWidget(right_column)

        vbox_right.addStretch(1)
        vbox_left.addStretch(1)

        self.setStyleSheet(f"""
            QWidget {{
                background-color: #222;
                font-family: '{font_family}';
            }}
            QFrame {{
                background-color: #333;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 7px;
            }}
            QLabel {{
                color: #37c6a5;
                font-size: 25px;
                font-family: '{font_family}';
            }}
            QPushButton {{
                background-color: #525252;
                color: white;
                border-radius: 8px;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-family: '{font_family}';
                
            }}
            QPushButton:hover {{
                background-color: #049372;
            }}
        """)

        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.show()

    def on_task_manager_click(self):
        import os
        os.system('taskmgr')

    def on_control_panel_click(self):
        import os
        os.system('control')

    def on_open_autostart_folder_click(self):
        import os
        os.system('explorer %APPDATA%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup')

    def on_open_cmd_click(self):
        import subprocess
        subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe')

    def on_open_registry_editor_click(self):
        import os
        os.system('regedit')

    def on_open_msconfig_click(self):
        import os
        os.system('msconfig')

    def on_open_sysprop_click(self):
        import os
        os.system('SystemPropertiesAdvanced')

    def on_open_process_hacker_click(self):
        import os
        os.system('explorer D:\\Process Hacker 2\\ProcessHacker.exe')

    def on_open_aida64_click(self):
        import os
        os.system('explorer C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AIDA64\\aida64.exe')

    def on_open_hard_disk_sentinel_click(self):
        import os
        os.system('explorer C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Hard Disk Sentinel\\HDSentinel.exe')

    def on_open_total_uninstall_click(self):
        import os
        os.system('explorer C:\\Program Files\\Total Uninstall\\Tu.exe')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
 

Пробовал сначала ввести эту команду, не получилось.
pyinstaller godmode.py --noconsole --add-data "nunito.ttf;." --name godmode --noconfirm

Потом решил сделать отдельную папку, запихнуть туда шрифт, повторить прошлые действия (предварительно заменив путь), но результат аналогичный.
А главное в PyCharm (Редактор) всё работает!

KindKing, отвечает ли https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1506816/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8-pyqt5/1511560#1511560 на ваш вопрос ?

Нет, не отвечает.

KindKing, в примере, который я вам предложил, показано как вшить какой-то шрифт в   .exe файл. Если вы по каким-то причинам не хотите это делать, то просто положите ваш nunito.ttf рядом с файлом  .exe и изображение icon.png тоже рядом с godmode.exe.

Блин, спасибо большое! Попробовал перекинуть файлы к .exe,  сработало!

KindKing, пожалуйста, но помните, что если вы собираетесь кому-то передавать свой .exe, то надо вшить шрифт и изображения в .exe, так будет правильно.
